# Prove PAC Learnable

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

How can I prove that a hypothesis space is PAC learnable?

The setup for this is X which is a discrete instance space.

H is a set of hypotheses over X. H contains all singleton functions as well as all negative functions.

Can someone walk me through how to prove this?